# Please help me to find the best choice for my sentence

Tags: word-request

Suppose you are watching a football match which has no interest for you. You have stood in ceremony with one of your close friends who is a fan of one side (one of the playing teams) and you feel shy to say you are not interested to watch that match anymore. Players performing very poor and the game has no excitement for audience. The only chance is that you began to watch the game not from the beginning. Game finishes and you tell in your wife's ear:

> - The only ... of the game was that it didn’t last long.

What would you use to fill in the blank?
My dictionary suggests:

> - a) advantage
> - b) good
> - c) goodness
> - d) good point
> - d) virtue

For me only 'd' works. Can you offer some more alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fill in the blank, I might say: **upside**. That feels very natural for me to say.

> The only upside of the game is that it didn't last long!

**Benefit** is another synonym but doesn't seem to accurately capture your mood.

You could also reword the sentence to something like:

> The only thing that made the game **tolerable** was that it ended quickly!

If you're feeling brave with figurative language, as an idiom of "redeeming quality," and allusion with more dramatic tones, you could say:

> The game's only **saving grace** was its brevity!

Or, more simply put:

> The game's only **redeeming quality** was its length!

Or, if you want to get a little more snarky:

> The **best part** of the game was when it ended!

I actually rather like that last one :) **Virtue** could definitely work in your sentence, although I usually think of the word virtue as having a strong association with morals and religious context. You can, of course, intentionally use words with more serious overtones as hyperbole, depending on your sense of humor, but this can be tricky.

Comment: @fetters_of_ennuie thank you very much; your answer contains lots of useful information regarding the matter in my question, but "saving grace" was something which I thought about and asked about it from other natives; they firmly rejected the possibility of the usage of this idiom. Do you confirm that I can use it to make the same sense like your 'upside' in my sentence to make the same feeling in the second person? Meanwhile please tell me a bit more about "redeeming quality"; does it mean the same too? and what about "good quality"?

Comment: @A-friend  Happy to help. Yes, in my view, you can absolutely use "**saving grace**." This is not a question of grammar, as it is grammatically correct. This is a question of writing style and sense of propriety and humor, which are subjective and up to the individual. You may want to take the feelings of your audience into consideration though. Let me explain (not enough room here)…

Comment: The only potential trouble I see arising with using "saving grace" is that the idiom is derived from the literal definition as ["God's grace."](http://www.gotquestions.org/saving-grace.html) So perhaps if you are speaking to a fundamentalist Christian or religious zealot, they might be offended that you would casually use figurative language alluding to a concept they take very seriously. Perhaps some might even take it literally. But I think this phrase is so commonly used as an idiom, the vast majority of people would understand it is not meant to be taken literally in a religious context.

Comment: In fact, [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/saving-grace) does not even mention a religious meaning. They define saving grace as: "a good quality that something or someone has that stops it, him, or her from being completely bad." That definition actually seems to match your sentiment perfectly. The example they give is even very similar to your scenario: "The film's only/one saving grace is the excellent cinematography" - implying the plot, characters, acting, writing - everything about the film was terrible, except for the cinematography.

Comment: [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/saving-grace) has a very similar definition: “a good quality or feature in a person or thing that prevents them from being completely bad or worthless” & similar example: “the saving grace of the play was the high quality of the acting.” Again we see things like plays & movies being used as examples; surely a sporting event could follow suit. Some might say a saving grace must be good by design and not by accident. Yet I use 'saving grace' to describe fortuitous serendipity all the time; so perhaps it's a humorous usage.

Comment: Many many thanks @fetters_of_ennui, but please as I asked from you please tell me more about "redeeming quality" too. Thank you again. Does it feet in my example making the same sense like "virtue" , "saving grace" and "upside"? and ofcourse about "good quality". Can I just say: "The only good quality of the game was that it didn’t last long."  Does it make any sense to you?

Comment: @A-friend Don't worry, I didn't forget. I just didn't want to overwhelm you with too much at once. Plus I needed a little break from typing :)

Comment: “**Redeeming quality**” might have a similar potential to allude to religious concepts, but to a lesser extent. Some Christians believe in the concept of “redemption,” which they associate with being forgiven of sins. However, the word “redeem” is used quite often in situations that have nothing to do with religion. To “redeem yourself” means simply to make up for some fault or wrongdoing. This could be to “God” (if you believe in God), but it could also be to your spouse, your students, your audience, etc. – anyone who can judge you.

Comment: So to say “it’s only redeeming quality” would mean the only good thing that makes up for all the bad things. I believe this works in your situation. The meaning is very similar to saving grace. In fact, Merriam Webster defines ‘saving grace’ as “a redeeming quality or factor”! But the different connotations of these two phrases can have different effects. The way these phrases are received depends on the personal biases of the person you’re speaking to. If you have a friend who is deeply religious and easily offended, perhaps I'd avoid using these idioms with him. Otherwise, I think it’s fine.

Comment: “**Good quality**” is much less specific and far less loaded with the potential to offend. I can’t think of another way to (mis)interpret “good quality” other than literally: a quality that is good. This phrase would also work in the sentence. As long as you say “*only* good quality” you can convey a meaning *similar* to “redeeming quality,” but *closer* to 'upside.' Using “redeeming quality” suggests that the “only good quality” is one that makes up for the bad, while merely saying “only good quality” does not convey any subtext about the significance of that quality. If that makes sense.

Comment: So, in summary, I think if you want to avoid being misunderstood, “only good quality” works. It just uses simpler language. If you aim for something more complex and creative, don't be afraid to try out one of those figurative idioms! Maybe just test it on someone who won’t be easily offended first. :)

Comment: @ferrers_of_ennui , you helped me at the real meaning of the word. I have no words to express my gratitude. Thank you very much  again for spending your time to help people like me who love to learn English, but have no chance to be among you natives at least for now. :)